# Get inner HTML of parent element with php and xpath

Tags: php, xpath, innerhtml

I'd like to get all of the content including tags of a parent element, let's say:

```
$imgs = $xpath->query('//img');
echo $imgs->item(0)->parentNode->innerHTML;
```

Of course, `innerHTML` attribute doesn't exist. The most similar attribute would be `innerText` that contains only text without tags. I really need the HTML. Is there a painless way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried `innerXml` or `nodeValue`?

Comment: Yes and they are the same as textContent. The solution is: echo $dom->saveXML($imgs->item(0)->parentNode);

Answer (score 0):

You could use another XPath expression instead (of selecting the parent node and innerHTML), `./../node()` which selects the parent element.

Using `node()` is important so you get both elements and text nodes.

If you know theres only one `<img/>` element, you can also use `//*[img]/node()`.