# Xpath query to get text in span with <H2> tags

Tags: php, xpath

i want to get all the text after the `<span class="general2">` including the `<h2>` tags

i have the Html content as following

```
    <span class="general2" itemprop="articleBody"> I WANT THIS TEXT <a href="url">I WANT THIS TEXT</a>I WANT THIS TEXT<br />

<h2>I WANT THIS TEXT AND ALSO PRESERVE THE TAG</h2><br />
I WANT THIS TEXT</span>
```

i tried the query

```
//span[contains(@class,'general2')]
```

but it gives me all the text as plain text. want something like

```
//span[contains(@class,'general2')]/*[text() or local-name()='h3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want quite distinct elements it is probably best to use the union operator `|` to join different elements together. You can first get all the text elements which are children of `<span/`, then also the text element of `<a/>` and last but not least the `<h2/>` element. This should work:

```
//span[contains(@class,'general2')]/text() | //span[contains(@class,'general2')]/h2 | //span[contains(@class,'general2')]/a/text()
```

Using XPath 3.0 this can be written more elegant as it allows functions as steps:

```
//span[contains(@class,'general2')]/(text() | h2 | a/text())
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the task of your host programming language. The XPath's job is only to select relevant element, then you need to find a way using PHP to get *inner HTML* markup of the selected element. Maybe something like this (I'm not PHP guy in any way) :

```
$span = $xpath->query('//span[contains(@class,'general2')]');
echo $dom->saveXML($span->item(0));
```

PHP References to get above snippet : [Get inner HTML of parent element with php and xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128737/get-inner-html-of-parent-element-with-php-and-xpath#comment26546683_18128737), [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)